# Program not running in Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```py
key_letters = [a, b, c]
encryption_key = 'hello world'

while True: 
    for i in range(len(encryption_key)):
        key_letters += [encryption_key[i]]
            if len(key_letters) == len(encrypt_text):
                break
```

I want this loop to iterate so the items in key_letters list iterate for the length of the encryption_key. When I run it in Colab, it just keeps on running, but nothing ever prints out (I know i don't have a print statement here, but just pretend there is)

Comment: please help us using a minimal reproducible code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask also, and show all the imports too